# rsync cannot delete non-empty directory

Tags: linux, rsync

When syncing my remote backup I get the error `rsync cannot delete non-empty directory`.

I know the cause: I have excluded some files and when rsync tries to delete a remote directory because it doesn't exists locally, it can't since it is not empty. Without the exclusion the directory would be emptied.

I also know I could get rid of the problem by using --delete-excluded, but that is not want I want.

I would like to skip uploading certain files (because they are too big for my upload speed), but I want to keep those I have already uploaded some time ago *if they exist locally*. If they do not exist locally, they should be deleted. --delete-excluded would delete them all on the remote side.

That also means that if a directory doesn't exists anymore locally, it should be deleted even if it contains excluded files.

Is it possible to setup rsync to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `p` modifier:

> A  p  indicates  that  a  rule is perishable, meaning that it is
>   ignored in directories that are being deleted.  For
>                 instance, the -C option’s default rules that exclude things like "CVS" and "*.o" are marked as perishable, and  will
>                 not prevent a directory that was removed on the source from being deleted on the destination.

For example, I use the `-F` option, which "tells rsync to look for per-directory .rsync-filter files that have been sprinkled through  the  hierarchy  and use their rules to filter the files in the transfer."

My `.rsync-filter` contains lines like these to filter out these "droppings" that Macs leave behind them:

```
-p .DS_Store
-p ._*
```

If using `exclude` instead of just `-`, add a comma. For example :

```
exclude,p .DS_Store
exclude,p Thumbs.db
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modifiers of include/exclude pattern, add -s on the pattern you used. It tell rsync that exclude rule only for send-side.

-n : only check what will delete on desc, don't delete
pattern: *.sh
desc: /home/kg/tmp

aim: 
want to delete file end of .sh on desc, but if you do this, you can't delete on the desc:
rsync -rvz --exclude *.sh --delete -n conkg kg@192.168.31.202:/home/kg/tmp

should change to : please add -n when you test
test: rsync -rvz --exclude-from del.txt -n --delete  conkg kg@192.168.31.202:/home/kg/tmp
real delete: rsync -rvz --exclude-from del.txt  --delete  conkg kg@192.168.31.202:/home/kg/tmp
cat del.txt
-s*.sh

or:
rsync -rvz --exclude -s*.sh --delete  conkg kg@192.168.31.202:/home/kg/tmp

Answer (score 0):

You could force deletion with this option:

`--force                 force deletion of directories even if not empty`

Answer (score -2):

just use the '--max-size=xx' and '--delete' options of rsync. It will do everything automatically and meet all your requirements.

Comment: It would at most be a workaround. I want to skip mov, avi and cr2 files completely because they generally are very large. But those I have already uploaded on a faster line some time ago should be kept. Now the problem is that the largest JPG files are bigger than the smallest CR2 files, so this solution is not ideal. I would rather use the exclude feature to filter on filenames.